# How do you create auto resizing a iframe when you make your browser smaller?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Does anyone know of a way to auto resize an iframe when you make your browser smaller??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize iframe when parent window resizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634582/how-to-resize-iframe-when-parent-window-resizes)

Comment: check this it is the best preview sample

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845452/how-to-render-a-full-webpage-in-smaller-iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a handler to the `window.onresize` event, and then resize your IFRAME appropriately.

I prefer jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('IFRAME').width($(window).width());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to specify the `<iframe>` size in percent.

Comment: I need the Height to auto resize

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it but I guess you could use a percentage width instead of a fixed width. In that case you should probably add a minimum width and height as well, to avoid that it is getting too small:

```
iframe
{
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   min-width: 300px;
   min-height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could as well use [this](http://www.ittreats.com/os/javascript/auto-resizing-iframe-height-in-the-page.html).

Basically it makes use of callResize()  in    Child  page    and   resizeIframe() in  Parent  page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without JavaScript if you'd like using CSS Media Queries. See this example here:

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/CSS3MediaQueries/Default.html

They are often used for "responsive design".