# Javascript modal popup to show external content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, modal-dialog

I am trying to implement a modal pop up window. The basic requirement is that I need to show an external page in a popup and the popup need to be a modal one.

I tried an implementation following this article http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/JavaScript-windowopen-Display-Modal-Popup-Window.aspx

And my implementation can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/geekays/8txau4v9/

The javascript code is here:

```
var popUpObj;

function showModalPopUp() {
    popUpObj = window.open("http://www.geekays.net/",
        "ModalPopUp",
        "toolbar=no," +
        "scrollbars=no," +
        "location=no," +
        "statusbar=no," +
        "menubar=no," +
        "resizable=0," +
        "width=950," +
        "height=600," +
        "left = 490," +
        "top=300");
    LoadModalDiv();
    popUpObj.focus();
}

function LoadModalDiv() {
    var bcgDiv = document.getElementById("divBackground");
    bcgDiv.style.display = "block";
}

//To be called when the pop-up is closed. But how??
function HideModalDiv() {
    var bcgDiv = document.getElementById("divBackground");
    bcgDiv.style.display = "none";
}
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="divBackground" style="position: fixed; z-index: 999; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; left:0; background-color: Black; filter: alpha(opacity=60); opacity: 0.6; -moz-opacity: 0.8;display:none"></div>
<div>
    Link is here: <a href="#" onclick="showModalPopUp();">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

But it is not working as expected. And the main issue is that I cannot call close action for the pop-up as the content is external.

I also tried using a local page with IFrame to load the external page. But using IFrame cause IE to show a security warning which is not welcome. I wanted to avoid the security warning. The warning can be suppressed using IE setting, but I have a large no of users and all of them might not like to change the default settings in their IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener that will ensure the modal div is hidden when the window has focus. Add the following line to your code:

```js
window.addEventListener("focus", function(event) { HideModalDiv(); }, false);
```

This way, once the pop is closed the parent window will regain focus.

Personally, I would also try exploring embedding an iFrame within a div, and creating a modal-like effect with CSS, but that could be a different story. For more info you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153310/fitting-iframe-inside-a-div).

Comment: This does not help as I cannot keep the pop-up on top all the time.