# Create Full Screen Iframe - WITH Space On Left For Navigation

Tags: html, css, iframe

So I have an application that has global navigation that sits on the left side of the page. Clicking this navigation updates an `<iframe>` that fills the remainder of the page.

I was able to get the `<iframe>` to fill the page, but adding this 160px margin on the left is proving difficult. I tried setting `left:160px` , `margin-left:160px`, `padding-left:160px` all to no avail.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? Code and Fiddle below:

```
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <iframe src="http://cnn.com" frameborder="0" name="product_iframe" id="main_iframe" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

  <style type="text/css">
    #main_iframe {position:fixed;height:100%;width:100%;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px; z-index:1}
    nav {position:fixed; left:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; width:160px; background:#333; color:#fff; z-index:2}
  </style>
```

[Here Is A Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2jm7xcz/1/)

Comment: well this looks like it's working.. do you want your nav to be inside the iframe?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153310/fitting-iframe-inside-a-div

Comment: It looks like it was working, but the NAV is hiding 160px of the iframe which was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iframe` can be tricky, and `width="100%"` is going to be problematic, because what you're really trying to is width-minus-160px.

In your case, wrapping another element around it to handle the left positioning will do the job: http://jsfiddle.net/x2jm7xcz/7/

The `iframe` element can then be 100% height/width of its parent.

Answer (score 2):

remove inline style on your iframe the use this

```
#main_iframe {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0px;
  left: 160px;
  width: -webkit-calc(100vw - 160px);
  width: calc(100vw - 160px);
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2jm7xcz/4/)

Comment: This is incredibly interesting. How compatible is this with the various browsers. Dynamic widths with CSS... that's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="main">      
<iframe src="http://cnn.com" frameborder="0" name="product_iframe" id="main_iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    float:left;
    width:160px;
    background:#333; 
    color:#fff; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0px; 
    bottom:0px; 
}

#main {
    margin-left: 165px;
    height:100%;
}
#main iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/robgir/chcxj746/

Comment: This was so close! Thanks for the help, I had to remove the `position:fixed` from the iframe and set the container to  `position:fixed` with some left, right, top, bottom, attributes and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your nav to be sort of  *inside* the iframe you will have to give the margin to the iframe itself, not the `#main_iframe`

```
#main_iframe iframe {
   padding-left: 160px;   
}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x2jm7xcz/3/)

*your question:*  you can simply add `#main_iframe iframe { padding-left: 160px; }` to just target your desired iframe and not push it off the right.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why you would target the iframe and not the ID. I don't want all iframes on my site behaving this way. Also this pushes the iframe 160px off the page to the right.

Comment: Cool, yeah wrapping the iFrame in a `<div>` was the key.  Thanks for the help.